# Avoid unwanted file name in zip in r

Tags: r, shiny

I am interested to download a zipped folder in `shiny R`. I am able to download it but it put the data file deep into that path. I have some example code below

```
output$downloadData1 <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste("output_", input$jobid, '.zip', sep = '')    
  },
  content = function(fname) {

    files2zip <- dir(file.path("/this/is/my/file/path",
                               counter,"outputfiles"), full.names = TRUE)
    zip(zipfile = fname, files = files2zip)
  },
  contentType = "application/zip"
)
```

It outputs the zip folder but the files are deep into  `/this/is/my/file/path",counter,"outputfiles"`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @zx8754 Same output

Comment: One possible way is `setwd(file.path("/this/is/my/file/path",                          counter)` and then `files2zip <- dir(file.path("outputfiles"), full.names = TRUE)`